# Tomcat Secure Websocket iOS 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'

Tags: ios, ssl, websocket, safari, java-websocket

My website connects with JavaScript to a JavaServer Websocket (Tomcat 7.0.76). I use Secure Websocket (wss) and all works as expected on Chrome (Windows/Linux), Android and older iOS devices, but on newer iOS devices, I get the following error:

**WebSocket connection to 'wss://****' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: 'Connection' header value is not 'Upgrade'**

But my SSL certificate is accepted by new iOS, I have no security warnings/problems navigating through the website via https.

Also, the websocket connection works over ws:// (by navigating to the site over http).

I think I have to modify the http header sent from the server, but no idea how to do that.

I am very grateful for any advice.

Comment: just to be clear, you get the error on client side?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work on real iOS devices, so for testing I used BrowserStack, and the error message appeared in the "simulated" dev console of iPhone in BrowserStack.

Comment: I switched to - now solved - question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50529119/prevent-tomcat-from-sending-header-connection-close