# Prevent Tomcat from sending header "Connection: close"

Tags: ssl, websocket, safari, tomcat7, java-websocket

My Tomcat Websocket Server has the attribute "Connection" double in the reply header for connections via https: "upgrade" and "close". Not for connections via http, only "upgrade" here. This will cause Safari to disconnect. How can I prevent "Connection: close" from appearing in the header?

Connector configuration :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true" scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="" keystorePass="" />
```

[image: Connection: upgrade and Connection: close]

Comment: Can I create an custom implementation of AbstractHttp11Processor where the "Connection: close" is set? I use Tomcat 7.0.76.

Comment: share your [Connector](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) configuration

Comment: <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector 
 port="8443" 
 protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"
    maxThreads="150" 
 SSLEnabled="true" 
 scheme="https" 
 secure="true"
 clientAuth="false"
 sslProtocol="TLS" 
 keystoreFile="***"
    keystorePass="***"
/>

Comment: There is no problem to connect via https to webpages but websocket via wss is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem by changing to Tomcat 9.0.8. I continue to use the same connector configuration.